# Displaying a image if no flash installed?

Tags: html, flash

I am having trouble displaying an image if no flash is installed.  I keep getting weird charcters displaying in a scrolling window. 
Here is my code:

```
<style>
    #MyFlashMovie {
        background: url("image/Year.gif");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 300px;
        width: 460px;
    }
</style>


<div ID="MyFlashMovie">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="height: 300px; width: 460px;" data="460x300.swf" >
        <param name="movie" value="460x300.swf" >
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" >
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" >
    </object>    
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Providing alternative images if Adobe Flash isn't available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449808/providing-alternative-images-if-adobe-flash-isnt-available)

Comment: Just put image tag inside the `<object>` tag of the flash.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect flash is install or not by JQuery and then show a image

```
var hasFlash = false;
try {
  var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
  if(fo) hasFlash = true;
}catch(e){
  if(navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined) hasFlash = true;
}
```

Comment: what i have got does work but when I turn flash off to test I can see weird characters and a scrolling window displaying through the image

Comment: When i put image inside the object I dotn get the image displaying at all only white screen with the weird characters and the scrolling window