# How to check user preinstalled applications on their machine ?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make a small landing page to diagnose all the requirements.

I want to to check if my user machine have :

- Adobe Reader
- Flash Player
- JavaScript must be enable

What is the best practice to build and check something like that ?

Is there any consideration that I need to keep in mind ?

Is there any tool outthere right now, that provide this kind of features already ?

I hope someone can at least point me to the right direction.

Thank-You.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291704/detect-from-browser-if-specific-application-is-installed

Answer (score 1):

You can show a message to the user if JavaScript isn't enabled using the noscript tag in HTML. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449808/providing-alternative-images-if-adobe-flash-isnt-available) shows how you can show something else if Flash is disabled/missing.

But there's no way to detect presence of Adobe Reader. Historically, it was common to just include a download button for Adobe Reader, but nowadays, PDFs are so universal that you can usually assume the user has a program on their computer that can handle them.

Answer (score 1):

Should be straight forward, to notify a user that javascript is disabled you can use the `noscript` tags.

Of course there's no way to run javascript if it's disabled, so the rest of the checks will fail.

To check for installed plugins, you check `navigator.plugins`

```js
var checkfor = {
    'Shockwave Flash' : false,
    'Adobe Acrobat'   : false
};

[].slice.call(navigator.plugins).forEach(function(x) {
    if (x.name in checkfor) checkfor[x.name] = true;
});


var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = 'JavaScript is enabled';
document.body.appendChild(p);

for (var key in checkfor) {
    if ( checkfor[key] ) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = key + ' is installed';
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f44k29d6/)

Comment: May I ask, why do you set them to false as a start ?

Comment: @841710176 - So I can set them to true if they are installed ?